# How to link selected instantiation of templated class/function?

Tags: c++, templates, linkage

Lets say, I have 3 classes, that provides same functions. They are unrelated in class hierarchy but they are implemented in such way to be similar to eachother.

- class A
- class B
- class C

For example purposes lets assume that A, B and C are arrays that hold some integers, but every class holds it in different way. Every class provides its iterator class and `class_name::begin()` and `class_name::end()`. Now I have some function template `foo` that increments every element of the array.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T & a)
{
    for(auto & element : a)
        element++;
}
```

But lets say that `foo` has enormously big body, that works for every type `T` as `A`, `B`, or `C`. How can I tell compiler:

> I will use only `foo<A>`, `foo<B>` and `foo<C>`. Let me move my function to .cpp file and link it.

The reason I am asking this is because templates are used to shorten code, that works for more than one compile-time-resolvable context. I don't want to write the same function inside .cpp file 3 times.

Comment: not sure if I understand the quesiton. What about `void foo_A(A& a) { foo<A>(a); }` ?